# Selective coloring of the text in TextBox (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, text-coloring

**Code in my MainPage.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextTextBox" 
          Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
          TextWrapping="Wrap" />

.
.
.

<!--Button with some Command-->
<Button x:Name="SearchButton" 
                    Content="Search" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Command}"/>
```

**Code in my ViewModel (property that is binded with TextBox)**

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return ssModel.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        ssModel.Text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

When you press SearchButton, is performing Command which return List of ints (this ints are indexes to coloring in TextBox).

For example I've Text:

> LoremIpsumDolorSitAmet

Then I press SearchButton, Command return me for example list of three numbers {2, 5, 13}. Now I want to coloring TextTextBox characters on this positions so, I want to get something like:

[image: Result what I want]

And this is exactly what I want to get. Coloring text in TextTextBox on the specified possitions.

I change TextBox to RichEditBox and write DependencyProperty to bind control with property in View Model. This is class with **DependencyProperty**:

```
public class RichTextC : DependencyObject
 {
    public static string GetRichText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RichTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRichText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RichTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RichText", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextC), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, callback));

    private static void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var reb = (RichEditBox)d;
        reb.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, (string)e.NewValue);
    }
 }
```

And **RichEditBox** at MainPage.xaml:

```
<RichEditBox local:RichTextC.RichText="{Binding MyRichText, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Margin="0,30,0,0""/>
```

But I have a another problem, because this DependencyProperty bind only in one way. When I set text/content of property at View Model control RichEditBox at MainPage will be notify and show new text. But when I change content of RichEditBox at MainPage it does not notify property in View  Model - so binding from View to View Model does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextBox doesn't support multi-coloured text. If you want editable coloured text you'll need to use the RichEditBox instead.

However, there isn't a direct way to bind to the text of a RichEditBox. You can set the text and its character formatting programatically through the RichEditBox's [ITextDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document.aspx) interfaces. For example, the following will set position 2 to Red. You can loop through your list of ints to set all of its ranges before calling ApplyDisplayUpdates:

```
ITextDocument doc = rtb.Document;
ITextRange range = doc.GetRange(2,3);
range.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
rtb.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
```

The other possibility would be to create a string with RTF codes in it and set that with ITextDocument.[SetText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.settext.aspx).

If you want to bind the Text you can create an attached property which accepts the RTF and calls SetText or which accepts your own simpler mark-up script and calls ITextRange.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor. Either way it would be similar to what I demonstrated to bind HTML to a WebView in my blog entry [Binding HTML to a WebView with Attached Properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties.aspx)

Comment: Thank You for Your post. I'm trying to use Your code, currently I'm testing so I use this code in MainPage constructor but it does not work. When should I set any text? I add this line _rtb.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "TestText");_ and then is call Your code.

Comment: Make sure the range isn't null (see edited code) and call this from outside of the constructor. In your search button handler should be fine.

Comment: Thank You once again. I'm really close to solve my issue. I have another question. Do You know how can I disable language coloring/highlight. I mean, I've non-English Operation System and when I write in my RichEditBox in English of course almost all text have red serrated line and I want to turn off this line.